# How can I manage my TP-Link switch?

Tags: network-adapter, switch

I have the TL-SF1005D TP-Link switch connected to a Cisco router and the router to the modem. I would like to know if that switch can be managed in a browser or some other way in order to turn off the LEDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

It is an unmanaged switch, it literally has no configurable settings at all; there's nothing in it to connect to, it's merely a pass-through device.

I'd suggest sticky tape, or blu-tack, etc - something removable for troubleshooting.

[Device manual](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201808/20180813/7106508151_TL-SF1005DTL-SF1008DTL-SF1016DTL-SF1024M_IG.pdf)